# How to compute $I_n=\int^{+\infty}_{0}x^ne^{-x}dx,\ n \geq 0$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to compute the following integral: $$I_n=\int^{+\infty}_{0}x^ne^{-x}dx,\ n \geq 0$$
How to do it?

Comment: Try integration by parts and establish a recurrence relation of $I_n$.

Comment: have tried by part and write $I_n$ on depending of $I_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Another idea, the Feynmann trick: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205797/differentiation-under-integral-sign-gamma-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also define $J(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x}dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and then differentiate this expression $n$- times with respect to $\alpha$. We get

$I_n=(-1)^n\frac{d^nJ(\alpha)}{d^n\alpha}|_{\alpha=1}= \frac{n!}{\alpha^{n+1}}|_{\alpha=1}=n!$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

By integration by parts you can find a recursive relation or directly you can use the Gamma function

$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
and that
$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$

Comment: The answer is $n!$, right?

Comment: Yes right!${}{}$