# Show $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx=n!$ for $n = 0,1,2,...$ without using gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the integral $$I_n = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx$$ and I want to show that $I_n = n!$ for $n = 0, 1, 2,...$ without using the gamma function. I have also shown that $I_n = nI_{n-1}$.

Many thanks.

Comment: All you need now is that $I_0=1$.

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty x^0e^{-x}\,dx=1$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205797/27978 also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First for $n=0$

$$
I_0 = \int_0^\infty x^0 e^{-x} dx
    =-\left[e^{-x}\right]_0^\infty=1=0!
$$

now suppose for some $k \in \mathbb N, I_k=k!$, so

$$
\begin{split}
I_{k+1}
 &= \int_0^\infty x^{k+1}e^{-x}dx \\
 &= \left[-x^{k+1}e^{-x}\right]_0^\infty
  + \int_0^\infty (k+1)x^k e^{-x}dx \\
 &= 0+(k+1)I_k\\
 &= (k+1)!
\end{split}
$$

Then by principle of mathematical induction $I_n=n!$ for all $ n\in \mathbb N.$

Comment: +1, nice answer. I took the liberty of editing the LaTeX to make it slightly more readable.

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks :)